# Conversion script in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to add UDT bom_object column in my table.

```
       bom_object type= list<bom_object>
```

which will replace the old column 'product'. for that i need to write conversion script.I will appreciate Any suggestion or idea. Since i am new to cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't completely understand your question. I am just guessing that you want to change the type of an existing column and you want a script to convert the existing data. Is it?

In that case, it is better to create a new column with your requirement. Read the previous data using an iterator and convert it to suit your new column and reinsert it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes, I wanted to read old data and insert in newely added column. any sample document is available to write that script?

Comment: You will need to write a JAVA or Python program to do it. 
eg: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/reference/queryBuilder_r.html

Please read the data and then write it. If the data is huge, you might want to distribute it using analytics.